# This sentence reads somewhat queer, but I can't tell exactly where is not correct.

Tags: sentence-construction

It's in a composition written by my son. It reads:

> Our campus ought to combine its environment with the nature other than those reinforced concrete buildings now we see.

Comment: It should be “rather than”？

Comment: I guess it should be!

Answer (score 3):

Three things: "with the nature" should be "with nature", as "the" says there is a particular nature to be combined with - not just "nature" as intended.

'Other' is not correct here, it says, in this context, that "the nature" includes those concrete reinforced buildings and we are looking for something else - this makes little sense, so as you say, it should be "rather".

Finally "now we see" has the wrong word order, it ought to be "we see now".

So the final version is "Our campus ought to combine its environment with nature rather than those reinforced concrete buildings we see now."